Awarding PlayFab items using Steam micropayments
I'm looking into adding micropayments to my standalone (Windows/Mac/Linux) Unity-based game, basically I want to allow my players to receive specific PlayFab items after completing a payment via Steam. I already have integrations set up with PlayFab and Steamworks API. I'm trying to read through the Steamworks Microtransactions Implementation Guide to see how to do it.
As I understand it I need to:

Write a Playfab Azure function that makes the microtransaction request with Steam on behalf of the player, using the WebAPI publisher key, so the game would call this function with the usual CloudScript API
PlayFab has to receive (somehow?) an authorization from Steam that actually grants the items, I assume with another Azure function?

I'm sure I'm not the first person implementing this, so I was wondering if I could find a specific guide somewhere? Note I'm using PlayFab Economy v2.
